# Real time Google charts with MySql

Tags: mysql, google-visualization

I'm doing a little web-survey where I have a form that when submitted has the data stored in a MySql table.
On the same website I have a couple of Google pie charts.
What is the easiest way to get data from my database and pass it to google javascript code?
I've been told that I'd need to create a php file that stores my data into an array and than returns a JSON string.
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: what's wrong with a php on server returning formatted JSON for pie chart

Comment: I don't know very well how to pass the JSON data to the chart so I was wondering if I could for instance do the the query directly from the google javascript.

Comment: I would be wary of using google charts for anything other than a toy project. You are making your website dependent on a third party and exposing your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Query will only allow you to query from google spreadsheets. If you have a mysql database, you will need to use whatever method (php most likely) to return a JSON object, and then feed that in to google.

There are many ways to do this, so please see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) on DataTable notation and how to input data to it.